# Como buscar caracteres em uma string em Assembly x86?

Tags: string, assembly, char, x86, nasm

Estou tentando reescrever o seguinte código C em Assembly x86

```
int myFn( char * v, char c, int size ) {
  int i;
  for(i=0; i < size; i++ )
    if( v[i] == c )
      return i;
  return -1;
}
```

Tentei utilizar o seguinte código em x86:

```
myFn:
  mov esi, 0
  mov ebx, [esp + 8]
  mov ecx, [esp + 12]

  FOR:
    mov eax, -1
    cmp esi, [esp + 4]
    jge ENDFOR

    cmp [ecx + esi], ebx
    je EQUAL

    inc esi
    jmp FOR
  
  EQUAL:
    mov eax, [esi]
  
  ENDFOR:

  ret
```

Porém não estou tendo o resultado esperado, tentei dar uma debugada e pelo entendi o problema está na segunda comparação `cmp [ecx + esi], ebx`, equivalente a `v[i] == c`, onde ebx possui o valor correto do char procurado mas [ecx + esi] me da o valor errado, provavelmente por não ser uma comparação byte-sized, no entanto não tenho ideia de como posso resolver

Comment: De bater o olho (não conheço x86) pode ser que esteja errada a reserva do stack frame (confira um a um os tamanhos dos espaços alocados para os parâmetros e mais a variável local) ou ainda o clássico índice avançando para fora do intervalo permitido no `for`.

Comment: Tentei dar uma debugada e pelo que eu vi o problema está na segunda comparação `cmp [ecx + esi], ebx`, equivalente a `v[i] == c`, onde ebx possui o valor correto do char procurado mas [ecx + esi] me da o valor errado, provavelmente por não ser uma comparação byte-sized, mas não tenho ideia de como resolver

Comment: Bom, apesar de simples (para quem entende) não é um [mcve], nesse caso voto pelo fechamento temporário da pergunta para que seja editada fornecendo o código reduzido, a fim de reabrir ou manter aberta.

Comment: O problema da comparação é que ela está utilizando um registrador de 32 bits (ebx), porém, no código em linguagem C a variável "c" e o vetor "v" são do tipo caractér (8 bits). Para comparar caractéres, você precisa utilizar um registrador de 8 bits (ex: bl). Veja o código gerado em assembly aqui: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cvdfTnv4a